# Sorting hash of arrays: Isolate only the largest arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, hash

I am able to sort a hash of arrays based on the size of the arrays according to the following code:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

my %HoA = (
flintstones    => [ "fred", "barney" ],
jetsons        => [ "george", "jane", "elroy" ],
simpsons       => [ "homer", "marge", "bart" ],
);

for my $key ( sort { @{$HoA{$b}} <=> @{$HoA{$a}} } keys %HoA ) {
    print "key: $key\tArray: @{$HoA{$key}} \n";
}
```

Output:

```
key: jetsons    Array: george jane elroy 
key: simpsons   Array: homer marge bart 
key: flintstones    Array: fred barney
```

I would like to isolate all of the arrays that are tied for being the largest for subsequent processing. In this case two arrays are tied for being the largest, each with size 3. My desired output would look something like:

```
key: jetsons    Array: george jane elroy 
key: simpsons   Array: homer marge bart
```

Comment: We need to see the code that's giving you problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'max';
use Data::Dump;

my %HoA = (
    flintstones => [ qw/ fred   barney / ],
    jetsons     => [ qw/ george jane  elroy / ],
    simpsons    => [ qw/ homer  marge bart / ],
);

my $max = max map { scalar @$_ } values %HoA;

dd [ grep { @$_ == $max } values %HoA ];
```

#### output

```
[["george", "jane", "elroy"], ["homer", "marge", "bart"]]
```

or, to exactly match your required output

```perl
while ( my ($k, $v) = each %HoA ) {
    next unless @$v == $max;
    printf "key: %-10s Array: %s\n", $k, "@$v";
}
```

#### output

```
key: simpsons   Array: homer marge bart
key: jetsons    Array: george jane elroy
```